# Implementing bounded parameters in JAGS

Tags: jags, r2jags

I have a simple hierarchical model that I am implementing in JAGS where I model length as a function of age as a single change-point regression, then model these variables against a site level parameter called temp. I would like to keep the cp parameter bounded within the minimum and maximum age for each site. I've tried looking at both `dinterval` and the `T(,)` construct in JAGS, but neither seem to do quite what I want. In my reprex below the `dinterval` function simply limits `cp` to 0 instead of the minimum age at a site.

EDIT: I realized after initial post that the parameters must be bounded on `theta_hat`, not on individual parameter naming as I originally posted (i.e. `cp[j] <- theta_hat[j, 4]`). Otherwise, the second-level model predictions will be incorrect.

Any thoughts or ideas for how I can keep `theta_hat` parameters bounded?

```
library(R2jags)

age1 <- sort(rep(2:8, 10))
age2 <- sort(rep(1:10, 10))
vb <- function(age, linf, k, t0) linf * (1 - exp(-k * (age - t0)))
len1 <- vb(age1, 100, 0.25, -0.5) + rnorm(length(age1), 0, age1)
len2 <- vb(age2, 80, 0.5, -0.75) + rnorm(length(age2), 0, age2)
laa_data1 <- data.frame(site = 1L, age = age1, len = len1)
laa_data2 <- data.frame(site = 2L, age = age2, len = len2)
laa_data <- rbind(laa_data1, laa_data2)

K <- 4 # number of parameters
W <- diag(4)

## Model ##
data = list(
  dat = as.matrix(laa_data),
  n = nrow(laa_data),
  nsites = 2,
  temp = as.vector(c(20,25)),
  # minage = c(min(age1), min(age2)),
  # maxage = c(max(age1), max(age2)),
  K = K,
  W = W
)

model <- function() {

for (j in 1:nsites){
  
  alpha[j] <- theta[j, 1]
  beta1[j] <- theta[j, 2]
  beta2[j] <- theta[j, 3]
  cp[j] <-    theta[j, 4]
  

  theta[j, 1:K] ~ dmnorm(theta_hat[j, ], theta_tau[,]) # is there a way to use T(,) to keep parameters bounded (or censored) here?

  # or should parameter bounding happen at this level?
  theta_hat[j, 1] <- a1 + (b1 * temp[j])
  theta_hat[j, 2] <- a2 + (b2 * temp[j])
  theta_hat[j, 3] <- a3 + (b3 * temp[j])
  theta_hat[j, 4] <- a4 + (b4 * temp[j])
}

# likelihood
for (i in 1:n) {
  mu[i] <- 
    alpha[dat[i,1]] + 
    beta1[dat[i,1]] * min(dat[i,2], cp[dat[i,1]]) + 
    beta2[dat[i,1]] * max(0,dat[i,2] - cp[dat[i,1]])
  dat[i,3] ~ dnorm(mu[i], 1/nu_alk)
}

# priors
a1 ~ dunif(-10, 10)
b1 ~ dunif(-10, 10) 
a2 ~ dunif(-10, 10)
b2 ~ dunif(-10, 10)
a3 ~ dunif(-10, 10)
b3 ~ dunif(-10, 10)
a4 ~ dunif(-10, 10)
b4 ~ dunif(-10, 10)

# priors on variance-covariance
theta_tau[1:K,1:K] ~ dwish(W[,], df)
df <- K + 1
nu_alk ~ dunif(0, 100)

}

params = c("theta_hat", "alpha", "beta1", "beta2", "cp") 

# Fit model
fit <- jags(
  data=data,
  parameters.to.save = params,
  model=model, 
  n.chains = 1,
  n.iter = 5000, 
  n.burnin = 1000,
  n.thin=5
)
```

Comment: How about `cp[j] ~ dunif(minage[j], maxage[j])`